# Drag and drop page design at run time

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, jquery-ui, bootstrap-4

I'm developing a business application. For example, I have a page with student information with First name and Last name the page was designed and deployed in the server. After a few days, user wants to add one more field, for example, Middle name. So now I want to redesign the form at run time like user just edit that student master page then drags and drop the new text box and redesign the entire page and map the API field also here consider we have the Middle name in API.

I'm looking for something like this.
     I'm designing a page with standard HTML and bootstrap while developing the application.
If I want to edit in run time means the entire page HTML will be load in separate page there I can design the page, i can place any kind of controls and place it any position. once the design is ready then i bring that HTML code and overwrite the existing files. so that I can get the new changes (If i want to compile the application means I can do it).

So here i will give some HTML code to a new page or control and design the page and get the new HTML code.

Comment: I would share what you have so far, and what your exact problem is.

Comment: I'm expecting something like this. Please refer this link http://www.vvveb.com/vvvebjs/editor.html